# Filter to check if an element fits condition and if yes... get NEXT element

Tags: javascript, arrays

`[ 'foo', 'foo@foo.com', 'bar.', 'bar@bar.com' ]`

This is the array.. I have to check which word starts or ends with a `.` and then return the email (which is the next element) if the word fits the requirement. So basically in this case `'bar.'` is the word I'm looking for.. and I need to use `filter` to return `'bar@bar.com'`. The word and e-mail are always one after another even in longer arrays with multiple elements to be returned.

```js
return logins.filter((el, i) => el.match(/^\..+|.+\.$/) && i % 2 === 0);
```

I only managed to return `'bar.'` .. don't know how to only check it and instead return the next element.
If somehow possible to include a ternary in `filter`.. and return next element if true?

Comment: You shouldn't use `filter()` for this.

Comment: And why would you use filter? Is there a specific condition that requires it?

Comment: `filter()` returns the array elements that satisfy the condition, you can't make it return a different element.

Comment: Hmm, you can use `logins[i-1].match(...)` to test the previous element.

Comment: yes.. I have to use filter. Maybe I should do something before using filter.. but I still have to include it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `i-1` to test the previous element when the current element has an odd index.

```js
let logins = [ 'foo', 'foo@foo.com', 'bar.', 'bar@bar.com' ];
console.log(logins.filter((el, i, arr) => i % 2 == 1 && arr[i-1].match(/^\.|\.$/)));
```

Comment: Thank you.. that's exactly what i needed

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find), like:

```
['foo', 'foo@foo.com', 'bar.', 'bar@bar.com']
  .find(
    (item, index, arr) => index > 0 && 
      (arr[index - 1].endsWith('.') || arr[index - 1].startsWith('.'))
  )
```

> The `find()` method returns the value of the first element in the
> provided array that satisfies the provided testing function.